# Is it possible to obtain a Brazil visa without confirmed travel plans? (US citizen)

Tags: visas, us-citizens, south-america, brazil

I'm a US citizen and I will be traveling to Argentina this winter. While I'm there, I'd like to make a short one-week trip into Brazil.

I haven't picked the dates yet, so I don't have my travel itinerary. I'd like to apply for my visa in the US before I leave.

Is it possible to obtain a tourist visa in this situation? I've read conflicting opinions on the topic. I know that I may be questioned upon entering and that I should have an onward/return journey booked upon entry, but what is required for applying for the visa in the first place? Does anyone have first-hand experience applying for a Brasil visa without confirmed travel plans?

Comment: I just read the form(it is in portuguese) that you have to fill to apply for the visa and on it you have to write when you expect to enter and leave Brazil, and you should also write your contact address at Brazil. So, you should have some plan before applying for the Visa, although it is not required to have tickets bought. But Brazil and US have been cooperating lately trying to revoke the need of visa between both countries. So I suggest you try to call to a Brazilian embassy and ask them if those info in the forms are really needed because they may allow you to leave it empty.

Comment: @hooray: The Brazilian Consulate refuses to answer visa questions by phone; you must send them an email. (My experience is that they respond pretty quickly, though)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Brazilian Consulate in New York](http://novayork.itamaraty.gov.br/en-us/tourism_visa.xml), you have to bring

> a copy of your round-trip ticket or a booked itinerary showing travel to and from Brazil (confirming the purchase of the ticket, with passenger’s name, itinerary, flight number and arrival/departure dates)

with you to the consulate to apply for a tourist visa.

Comment: This is accurate and is the _official_ stance on the subject. I'm holding out on accepting this answer for now in hopes that someone with first-hand experience can provide more info. Based on my reading it is possible to get a visa without a pre-purchased ticket, but I'd like to know under what circumstances or if it's more random.

Comment: I've applied for a visa with arbitrary dates that were a rough best-guess, and an itinerary that was booked but not yet ticketed, and the visa application was successful. If you're particularly worried buy AND ticket a refundable fare, then cancel it. You have 90 days from when the visa is issued to enter the country or it is forfeit, and once you have the visa there are no problems entering any time during that 90 days. So making up some dates, getting an itinerary and just applying is a feasible approach.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just get a Brazilian visa at the Brazilian embassy in Buenos Aires or at one of the consulates in Cordoba, Mendoza or Puerto Iguazu while you are staying in Argentina? The entry requirements and costs will be the same as if you were applying in the USA.

Note, if you want to visit the Iguaçu falls, it used to be possible to do a day visit without a Brazilian visa, but I'm not sure if that's still the case. Also, the Brazilian consulate in Puerto Iguazu on the Argentinian side used to issue visas quickly with just a day or two wait, but again still not sure if that's the case.

Comment: I don't believe US citizens can apply for this visa outside of the US (unless they have residency status in the other country).  See [related question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/17647/444).

Comment: It's not legally possible, but the 'day visit to Iguazu without visa' is still technically possible, or it was in 2011. Just take the local bus between Puerto Iguazu and Iguaçu Falls and stay on (don't disembark) with all the locals when you get to the checkpoint.

Comment: This rule might be specific to Argentina. If it is, perhaps you could get one at the Brazilian consulate in Uruguay. It's very easy to get to Uruguay from Buenos Aires, you just take a ferry.